# Disable motherboard floppy controller DOS

Tags: ms-dos, floppy-drive, bios

I have a SuperMicro P4SCA motherboard ([manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/E7210/MNL-0697.pdf)) running FreeDOS 1.3. The motherboard has an onboard floppy controller as part of a W83627HG ([datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Nuvoton%20PDFs/W83627HF,F,HG,G.pdf)). However, this floppy control fails to provide some functionality I need, so I purchased an Adaptec AHA-1522A ([manual](http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/aha1520a_ug.pdf)) ISA card, which has a DP8473 FDC ([datasheet](https://www.wdj-consulting.com/blog/floppy-lit/DS009384.PDF)) that does provide the functionality I need. However, the AHA-1522A requires that the motherboard floppy controller be disabled to function correctly. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to disable the motherboard FDC. In particular, I did not see anything in the BIOS (Phoenix AwardBIOS) about disabling the FDC.

Is it possible to do this and, if so, how? Is this necessarily a BIOS setting, or is it possible to do from DOS? Do I maybe need to update my BIOS? I can post pictures of relevant BIOS pages, if desired.

Comment: IIRC that's a Pentium 4 board ca 2010 - long way to go to make it on topic for RC.SE.

Comment: Maybe, but considering the post is about FDCs and FreeDOS, it would seem out of place on a more modern forum.

Comment: I would argue that at this point, anything involving floppies is retro — and we allow questions about modern hardware to use floppies on modern systems (Greaseweazle etc.). So I would say this is question is OK, albeit unlikely to get a productive answer unless someone has figured out to configure the W83627HG to disable its floppy controller.

Comment: @MattHusz Not sure how you want to define it, but for RC.SE anything still in development - and FreeDOS is quite active developed - is considered modern. Also, your question is obviously not about the floppy controller, but about that modern (2010) mainboard, as you explicit ask about how to disable it. Isn't it?

Comment: Well it's about both, isn't it? But it's also about the software that runs on it, which may just be the BIOS, but could also include DOS. It may be obvious to you that all that matters here is the BIOS, but that's not obvious to me. And as for FreeDOS, that's a modern API-compatible implementation of an old OS. So if I'd installed MS-DOS instead of FreeDOS would that make this a retro question, even though I probably would have done everything the same way? That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, especially since I don't know many forums where DOS questions are prominent.

Comment: @MattHusz MS-DOS would still not make it an RC.SE question. The way it's described the question is not about any MS-DOS feature but about the modern board, its modern BIOS and your wish to manipulate either (or both).

Comment: In a sensible world, setting the 'type' of both floppies to 'None' would disable the floppy controller.  Does it?

Comment: @another-dave I wasn't able to get that to work. When I set both types to 'None' and plug the drive into the AHA-1522A and use ImageDisk's testfdc, I see the message "BIOS reports drive A: as Not installed." If I leave the original BIOS setting (and plug the drive into the AHA), I get a message about "No FDC interrupt". I suppose it's possible the AHA-1522A is faulty, but I see a message about it's BIOS during boot.

Comment: Did you try to just plug in the AHA-1522? Some modern BIOSes probe for ISA-connected FDCs, parallel ports and serial ports and automatically disable/reconfigure the on-board ports to avoid conflicts. Some not-so-modern BIOSes did that, too, like the IBM PS/2 model 30 BIOS ;)

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Yeah when I plug it in (and leave all BIOS setttings) I can't communicate with the floppy drive. I see a message about "No FDC interrupt" when using ImageDisk.

Answer (score 3):

You have already identified the Super I/O chip, and found the datasheet.

The datasheet describes on p. 80 how to get into "extended function mode", which is needed to access the control register.

Bit 0 of register CR22 is called "FDCPDN", which translatse to floppy-disk-controller power-down, so I assume if you write a zero to that bit, then the floppy part will power down.

Other functionality is register CR30 ("activation control" for the logical device of the floppy, possible you have to disable this, too).

You can also use register CR60 and CR61 to set the base address of the floppy controller, so if this is exposed in your BIOS, you could also use this to move the floppy controller away from the port range occupied by the external controller.

If neither disabling the floppy nor setting the base address is not possible with your BIOS, then maybe this functionality is not included in your BIOS.

So finding a BIOS update which would include this functionality would be best (but that's unlikely).

You could also try to modify the BIOS yourself, which would be the next best solution, but that's a lot of work, as you first need to reverse-engineer the BIOS: Find the code that initializes the Super I/O chip, and modify the values written to disable the floppy.

In principle, you could also write a small assembler program that does it after you boot from the harddisk. However, that would mean that during power-up both floppies react to the floppy port addresses, which is not ideal, and may screw up the configuration process, so you also may have to properly initialize the floppy controller and corresponding BIOS RAM locations after your powered down the onboard controller.

All of these require that you are skilled in assembler programming.

---

I also had a look at the AHA-1522A manual, and it looks like you cannot adjust the base address of the floppy controller on that card (which would have been another way to resolve the port conflict).

In case you come across any port base settings: The first floppy controller is typically at `0x3f0`, the second at `0x370`.